# Install-config.yaml - how to choose different machine type for master and worker nodes openshift cluster installation?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, openshift, redhat, openstack

I am deploying openShift cluster (ocp)  on openstack environment with 3 master and 3 worker node.For that I have generated the install-config.yaml file using "openshift-install" command. I want to use different flavour for master (m1.xlarge) and worker (m1.2xlarge). How Can I define this in install-config.yaml file?

Below is my install-config.yaml file -

```
apiVersion: v1
baseDomain: abc.com
compute:
- architecture: amd64
  hyperthreading: Enabled
  name: worker
  platform:
    openstack:
      additionalSecurityGroupIDs:
      - 61dfe2fb-889a-4d21-a252-608f357ae570
  replicas: 3
controlPlane:
  architecture: amd64
  hyperthreading: Enabled
  name: master
  platform:
    openstack:
      additionalSecurityGroupIDs:
      - 61dfe2fb-889a-4d21-a252-608f357ae570
  replicas: 3
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: tb
networking:
  clusterNetwork:
  - cidr: 10.128.0.0/14
    hostPrefix: 23
  machineNetwork:
  - cidr: 10.0.0.0/24
  networkType: OpenShiftSDN
  serviceNetwork:
  - 172.30.0.0/16
platform:
  openstack:
    apiFloatingIP: 10.9.7.10
    ingressFloatingIP: 10.9.7.11
    apiVIP: 10.0.0.5
    cloud: openstack
    defaultMachinePlatform:
      type: m1.2xlarge     < ==== M1.2 xlarger is being used for both worker and master
      rootVolume: {
        size: 200,
        type: "tripleo"
      }
    externalDNS: null
    externalNetwork: testbed-vlan1507
    ingressVIP: 10.0.0.7
publish: External
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/installing/installing_openstack/installing-openstack-installer-custom.html#installation-osp-config-yaml_installing-openstack-installer-custom), you should add `type: <flavor>` in platform.openstack, for example:

```yaml
compute:
- architecture: amd64
  hyperthreading: Enabled
  name: worker
  platform:
    openstack:
      type: ci.m1.xlarge 
      additionalSecurityGroupIDs:
      - 61dfe2fb-889a-4d21-a252-608f357ae570
  replicas: 3
```